# What does a comma between numbers mean in guitar tablature

Tags: guitar, notation, tablature

I have Guitar Pro installed on my machine. Guitar pro is a software that makes sounds according to the tablature you open. I'm curious about a symbol that I don't know what it means. It's a tilde but in the bass; it seems a comma right in the middle, not in the left, between the two notes. Thanks for all.

UPDATE: This symbol [image: weird-symbol]

It doesn't appear on the manual.

UPDATE 2: Probably the slide is bad printed because it's shorter than these.
This is what it appears on the manual.

[image: slides]

Comment: The Guitar Pro manual explains what the symbols mean in Guitar Pro: https://download-ca-5.guitar-pro.com/gp6/GP6%20Users%20Manual%20EN.pdf There is some variation in how symbols are used by different engravers, so you should look specifically for the Guitar Pro usage. Published tab books usually have a page that shows what the symbols used in the book mean.

Comment: Tab is still somewhat embryonic, and hasn't quite reached total standards - a little like drum music, where personal foibles are apparent.

Comment: Hard to tell from that tiny image, but that looks like a slide from the 12th to the 14th fret on the 3rd string. Slides are usually indicated by slanted lines, that line is so small that it looks sort of like a comma.

Comment: The *slide* (pictured in the update to the question) is described on page 22 of the manual.

Answer (score 3):

That is definitely a slide, indicating you play that note on the 12th fret then keeping the finger on that string slide it up to the 14th fret.

Normally the slide symbol is a little more obvious than that - but it is an angled line, either up or down.

More generally, tab websites and books typically have a key explaining all the symbols, and stealing from @Todd's comment, Guitar Pro has a [manual with symbols](https://download-ca-5.guitar-pro.com/gp6/GP6%20Users%20Manual%20EN.pdf) detailed and explained.